# Customize Kubernetes HPA Scaling Algorithm

Tags: kubernetes, horizontal-pod-autoscaling

I'm trying to auto scale pods on kubernetes using HPA ,but I need to customize HPA scaling algorithm which is  (desiredReplicas = ceil[currentReplicas * ( currentMetricValue / desiredMetricValue ) .It's not suitable for my requirements, can we use our own  HPA scaling algorithm

The current HPA scaling algorithm  use average value of metrices for pod scaling but I don't want to scale using average value.

In my case the issue with average value is that suppose there are three pod running pod-A cpu utilization is 90% ,Pod-B  cpu utilization  is 20%  and Pod-C is 20% and targetAverageCPUUtilization is 80% so Pod-A cpu usage is above 80% but HPA will calculate average of all three pods which would be 43% so it won't scale up .that's the issue with average value

Comment: Where are you running your K8S cluster?

Comment: Is your issue resolved?if yes, can you post the procedure you've followed as Solution and accept it for the greater visibility of community

Comment: not resolved yet @SaiChandiniRouthu